# How can I configure Debian workstations to be able to use a name provided by HP Laserjet printer

Tags: linux, debian, ping, hosts

I have a LaserJet printer connected to the network (2300DN), which I would like to access using the name you set up in the Jet Direct options. It works perfectly fine on WinXP machines, I couldn't configure it on Linux (using Debian). After installing winbind `ping lj2300dn` just hangs. How can I get it configured correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2300DN should have mDNS support - `apt-get install libnss-mdns avahi-daemon` on the Debian machines and then you should be able to ping lj2300dn.local.

The other thing is it should be sending broadcast packets that CUPS will pick up on, so you could install CUPS on all machines, add the printer on one of them (ideally a server) then edit `/etc/cups/client.conf` and set `ServerName` to that machine.

Comment: I actually had these packages installed, I just didnt' realize I need to use the .local naming. Thanks very much!